# How can i create a zipped file made of a choice of FileFields/ImageFields when i save my model object?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

**edit**: the code to create the zip file and add it to my `zip_press_kit` field actually works, but i still can't get the url to download it in my template (see points 4 and 5 to see what appends)

1) I have a model:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    press_kit = models.FileField(upload_to='press_kit/',
                                 verbose_name="Dossier de presse",
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True,
                                 default=None)
    high_res_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to='high_res_covers/', 
                                 verbose_name="Couverture HD",
                                 blank=True)
    zip_press_kit = models.FileField(upload_to='zips/',
                                 blank=True,
                                 null=True)
```

I just gave the fields i'm interested into.
So when i save my new Book object in the django-admin i want to check if i have a `high_res_cover` OR a `press_kit`, and if so, create a `zip_press_kit` that would be a zip file containing the `high_res_cover` and/or the `press_kit`.

2) I have a save method:

```
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    zip_file_name = f"{slugify(f'{self.title}-{self.id}')}.zip"

    if self.high_res_cover or self.press_kit:

        with ZipFile(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}zips/{zip_file_name}', 'w') as zip_file:

            if self.high_res_cover:
                zip_file.write(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}{self.high_res_cover}', os.path.basename(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}/{self.high_res_cover}'))

            if self.press_kit:
                zip_file.write(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}{self.press_kit}', os.path.basename(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}/{self.press_kit}'))

        self.zip_press_kit = File(open(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}/zips/{zip_file_name}', 'rb'))

        os.remove(f'{MEDIA_ROOT}/zips/{zip_file_name}')

    else:
        self.zip_press_kit = None

    super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This code works when my book already exists and I call save on it but when i want to get the URL of the file in my template i get something like 'localhost:8000/Users/me/Desktop/ProjectFIle.../'.

3) Tree of the project:

```
.
├── Entremonde
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── Pipfile
├── Pipfile.lock
├── __pycache__
│   └── manage.cpython-37.pyc
├── books
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── management
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── commands
│   │       ├── __init__.py
│   │       ├── __pycache__
│   │       │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       │   └── books_init.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       └── books_init.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_book_display.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── books
│   │       └── js
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── books
│   │       ├── authors.html
│   │       ├── book.html
│   │       └── catalogue.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── contacts
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── 0002_contact_postal_code.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       ├── 0002_contact_postal_code.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── contacts
│   │       ├── contacts.html
│   │       └── esapce-pro.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── db.json
├── manage.py
├── media
│   ├── covers
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── 25RUPTURE-Couverture_fisher_600px_web.jpg
│   ├── ebooks
│   ├── high_res_covers
│   │   └── HDj_tschichold-nouvelle_typo-couv.jpg
│   ├── posters_events
│   ├── press_kit
│   │   ├── ...
│   │   └── DPentremonde-dossierdepresse_fisher-2.pdf
│   └── zips
│       └── le-realisme-capitaliste-none.zip
├── news
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── apps.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
│   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── news
│   │       └── rencontres.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── authors.css
│   │   ├── elements.css
│   │   ├── entremonde-style.css
│   │   ├── font.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── js
│       ├── author.js
│       └── script.js
└── templates
    └── base.html
```

4) how i import the url in my template (also tried with `book.zip_press_kit.url` ):

```
<div id="press-kits">
    {% for book in books_with_press_kit %}
        <a href="{{ book.zip_press_kit }}" class="e-font-large">{{ book.title }}</a><br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

5) What i get when i click the link:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/Users/pshop/Desktop/Entremonde/media/zips/le-realisme-capitaliste-2_QAeRykR.zip

Comment: How are you creating the URL in the template? And what *exactly* happens when you create a new book?

Comment: thanks for the answer.
 Since i flushed my base and created new items i don't have errors anymore when i save my new books and the zip file is created in the media/zips directory. but when i click on the link i have a 404 error. I edited my answer for more details, see points 4 and 5.